# iOS Xcode Swift Combining Input FirstName and LastName into a FullName Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I am having trouble combining a first and last name for this code I am running to update it to a tableviewcell. It seems as if it is not saving either first or last name and merely replacing it as I type new text in. I am not sure what is going on and I am certain the row numbers that I am using in my .plist match with the code. Any help with this or other alternatives are appreciated.

```
func textfieldTextWasChanged(newText: String, parentCell: CustomCell) {
    let parentCellIndexPath = tblExpandable.indexPathForCell(parentCell)

    let currentFullname = cellDescriptors[0][12]["primaryTitle"] as! String
    let fullnameParts = currentFullname.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    var newFullname = ""

    if parentCellIndexPath?.row == 13 {
        if fullnameParts.count == 2 {
            newFullname = "\(newText) \(fullnameParts[1])"
        }
        else {
            newFullname = newText
        }
    }
    else {
        newFullname = "\(fullnameParts[0]) \(newText)"
    }

    cellDescriptors[0][12].setValue(newFullname, forKey: "primaryTitle")
    tblExpandable.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What most likely is happening is that when you're calling tblExpandable.reloadData(), cellForRowAtIndexPath is getting called, and it's overwriting your changes that you're making here. You either need to do some cell caching or possibly consider using a UIScrollView instead of a UITableView.